# Can't insert images into post in wordpress when on live server

Tags: php, html, wordpress, media

I am currently using wordpress 4.4 with the following plugins installed:

1. Add this sharing buttons
2. advanced custom fields
3. custom post type ui
4. tg facebook comments
5. ultimate social media plus
6. velvet blues updates urls
7. wp mail smtp

My problem is the following:
My image does not display in my posts when I add one via the add media button. Instead it sends me out of the dashboard and unto this url: http://my_domain_name/wp-admin/post.php. I can upload images, I can choose images, I can even set them as featured image but it just won't let me add them in between my blogs via the add media button.

Furthermore, this problem only occurs on my live server but everything works fine on my local xampp server. What could be the problem with this.

Note: I checked my host and permission for dir "wp-content/uploads is already set to 755.

Comment: can you please show us your effort?

Comment: @manetsus this is the youtube link (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=soJML3CRWSo&feature=youtu.be) to how my problem looks like. It doesnt seem to be a permission problem since that one is set to 755 in my host.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you very much for all your input. I was able to solve my problem. It was a server issue. I notified my hosting provider and they were able to sort things out. Happy new year :)

Answer (score 1):

Set 755 recursive permission to this dir "wp-content/uploads". 
And also check `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size` parameters in your hosting server. May be your server configuration not allow big size of image.

Comment: hi wiram I use philwebservices as a host and they utilize a standard cpanel. It is very identical to that of hostgator. So when I followed your instructions I saw that the permission setting was already at 755. With regards to the image size, they are only minimal. Less than a 100kb.

Comment: Check server error log, Might be your site have some other issue you need to debugging php error. Enable php error reporting in Wordpress than you will see exact error while you upload the file.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem. It was a server issue. I called up my hosting provider and they fixed things. Thank you very much for your help. Happy new year!

Comment: Happy new year!! Roger :D

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the write permission on your server for the /wp-content dir or the directory where your file will save.

In localhost it will work fine because by default all the protection's are disabled.

Some websites for your references.

https://in.godaddy.com/help/set-directory-permissions-windows-6481

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E-uyCJ4Gxog

Comment: hi there, I use philwebservices as a host and they utilize a standard cpanel. It is very identical to that of hostgator.Permission is automatically set to 755.

Answer (score 0):

Check your server permission for images

Comment: hi there, I use philwebservices as a host and they utilize a standard cpanel. It is very identical to that of hostgator.Permission is automatically set to 755.